# Generate random password - Login into Google App Engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-activity, nosql

I'm implementing a `Password Forgotten` form into my Android Client.

What I'm really stuck in, is about generating a random password, match with database in `Google AppEngine endpoint` and let the user login into the app.

[image: Example printscreen]

I can't find any tutorial regarding this.

Is there some demo implementation or doc I could read to understand better this process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its quite simple.

- Generate a random string using [Apache Commons RandomStringUtil](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) and generate a hashcode for the same using some algorithm like MD5, RSA etc.
- Send the same to the user via email when the user submits the forget password form.
- Then redirect user to an intermediate screen where he need to enter this encoded hashcode, and once the hashcode matches then redirect the user to another screen where he/she needs to enter a new password.

Comment: Ok, good idea, I'm going to develop something like that, thanks